# send a data from javascript in view to a function in mvc

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

i have a class that contains 1 function.
how can i send a parameter from javascript in myview to this function?
and how can i get return value .
my class :

```
public class CityClass { 
    public static long GetIdCountryWithCountryText(string countryy) 
    { 
        using (SportContext db = new SportContext())
        {
            return db.tbl_contry.FirstOrDefault(p => p.country== countryy).id;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> how can i send a parameter from javascript in myview to this function?

You simply can't. javascript doesn't know anything about functions. It doesn't know what C# or a static function is. It doesn't know what ASP.NET MVC is neither.

You could use javascript to send an AJAX request to a server endpoint which in the case of an ASP.NET MVC application is called **controller action**. This controller action could in turn invoke your static function or whatever.

So you could have the following controller action:

```
public ActionResult SomeAction(string country)
{
    // here you could call your static function and pass the country to it
    // and possibly return some results to the client.

    // For example:
    var result = CityClass.GetIdCountryWithCountryText(country);
    return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Now you can use jQuery to send an AJAX request to this controller action passing the country javascript variable to it:

```
var country = 'France';
$.ajax({
    url: '/somecontroller/someaction',
    data: { country: country },
    cache: false,
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(result) {
        // here you could handle the results returned from your controller action    
    }
});
```

Comment: ok thanks . can i set the result to model? i mean fill a field in my model . for example id .